# Rails server suddenly not responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, halt

My `Rails 4.2.6` production server worked perfectly for long time.
Today I've added some functionality & migrated the server, everything looked fine until after some time of using the application the server become unresponsive.

The logs looks fine, the last request to the server worked without any errors, and the server still running but not unsering any requests.

Any clues? directions?

**EDIT:**

Looking at the docker logs I can see some errors on SSL:

```
[2017-06-07 15:06:10] ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_accept SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
        /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:401:in 'accept'
```

P.S. on of the main updates in the application is adding SSL certificate to the application.

Comment: is there Apache or Nginx handling the server?

Comment: Is there are particular endpoint that is failing to work? Have you monitored the memory usage?

Comment: @kiran.koduru the server is webrick its a small app for about 10 users, and there is about 1.3 GB of free memory on the machine

Comment: @MichaelGorman No, It's webrick inside a Docker container that worked perfectly for over 3 months

Comment: Did you check both the rails logs and the docker logs?

Comment: @MichaelGorman please see my latest edit